# Probability Distribution Function of the Height of Nodes in Full Binary Trees

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions, trees

I would like to understand the distribution of node heights in the space of full binary trees with a fixed number of leaves, $n$. That is, given a random full binary tree with $n$ leaves how likely is it that there will be a leaf with height equal to one? Given the relationship between such trees and Catalan numbers (see below) I expect there are some results out there but I am having trouble finding good sources and references.

**Additional Context**

A *full binary tree* is a binary tree such that each node has either zero or two children. For example, the $(n-1)$st [Catalan Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) is the number of distinct full binary trees with $n$ leaves. Below is a picture of the $C_3 = 5$ full binary trees with four leaves:

[image: Full binary trees with four leaves. (Public Domain)]

In this example we see that,

$$
\begin{align}
    \mathbb{P}[\text{height} = 1] &= 0.2, \quad \textit{(four nodes out of twenty)}\\
    \mathbb{P}[\text{height} = 2] &= 0.4, \\
    \mathbb{P}[\text{height} = 3] &= 0.4, \\
    \mathbb{P}[\text{height} = 4] &= 0.0, \\
    & \;\,\vdots
\end{align}
$$

Given a number of leaves, $n$, is there a general formula for this height distribution? Is there an appropriate continuous version of this distribution? In my search I've found statements about the height of the *trees* but not the heights of the *leaves* of the trees.

Comment: Doesn't the recurrence relation for the number of full binary trees help?  I'm too sleepy to try it myself at the moment.

Comment: Reference. Computing these for e.g. seven internal nodes we obtain for leaves of height one, two etc. up to seven the distribution $264, 528, 720, 768, 640, 384, 128,$ which points to [OEIS A108747](https://oeis.org/A108747), where a closed form and a generating function are given.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel -- Thank you for the reference! It didn't occur to me to check OEIS but now I'll make that a go-to. Based on that and some investigation in the literature there is a relationship involving *the number of Dyck paths of semilength $n$ with $k$ returns to the horizontal axis*. (See [OEIS A106566](https://oeis.org/A106566).) However, there is an additional $2^k$ factor in the function you referenced where I'm still trying to figure out where it comes from and how it relates to Dyck paths, in general.